# if statement and Test-Path (creating folder to remote systems)

Tags: powershell

I have tested a lot of commands and I seem to have come to a road block and looking for assistance.

1. This code I have works when I run this on ComputerA. ComputerA has the HomeFolder directory located on the D: drive. The text file has 2 machine names for now for testing purposes. A folder called "NewCreation" is then created to both ComputerB and ComputerC. Which is perfect.

```
Get-Content "D:\HomeFolder\MachineNames.txt" | %{New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "\\$_\d$\NewCreation" -Force -Verbose}
```

But the issue is when there's a computer in the environment that has this folder(NewCreation) already existed with tons of other sub-folders and files I am looking to make an if statement that if this folder exist, I want to rename it to "NewCreation_OLD" and create the folder "NewCreation".

2. Here's my attempt and I know it's not perfect or it doesn't work I've spend hours and searching and I'm wasting a lot of time. So yeah... I would greatly appreciate all the pointers and help from everyone!

```
$Folder = Get-Content "D:\HomeFolder\MachineNames.txt"

foreach ($Folders in $Folder){
    if (Test-Path -Path "\\$_\d$\NewCreation")
    {
        Rename-Item -Path "\\$_\d$\NewCreation" -NewName NewCreation_OLD -Force -Verbose
        New-Item -Path "\\$_\d$\" -Name NewCreation -ItemType Directory -Force -Verbose
    }
    else{
        Write-Host "Do something else"
    }
}
```

Comment: `$_` is meant to be used on `ForEach-Object` / `.foreach(..)` method. You're using a classic `foreach` loop, in this case it should be replaced by `$folders`

Comment: How would I call on each computernames in the text file then point it to a specific folder to detect that it is there and then rename it/create a new folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close, the only real issue was the use of [the automatic variable `$_`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#_) (also known as `$PSItem`) instead of the [`$item` from your `$collection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_foreach?view=powershell-7.2#syntax):

> `foreach ($<item> in $<collection>){<statement list>}`

I have added some comments for guidance.

```
# $computers instead of $Folder, for clarity
$computers = Get-Content "D:\HomeFolder\MachineNames.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers)
{
    # If this folder exists in this host
    if (Test-Path -Path "\\$computer\d$\NewCreation")
    {   
        # Rename it
        Rename-Item -Path "\\$computer\d$\NewCreation" -NewName "NewCreation_OLD" -Force -Verbose
    }

    # Here we can assume that the folder was not there or was renamed, so we can create it
    New-Item -Path "\\$computer\d$\" -Name NewCreation -ItemType Directory -Force -Verbose
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I see where I went wrong :) Have a good one!

Comment: @RunnerXdays my pleasure, happy to help :)